# Tokens received but not showing in balances

Tags: token

Playing with tokens I see I can send them and they show in the transactions ledger but don't show in the balances list. Do I need to change/allow trust in order to show them in balances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Put the address of the token (For example 'sureremit.co' for SureRemit) as a trusted anchor in the trustlines menu in most wallets.